# Unable to push key value pair to an array correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am trying push some key-value pairs in an array (**gp**) inside a for loop. But the values stored in the gp arrays are like **"key": 0**, where key should be **a** which is an output of **array[i]** and value should be **0**, which is correctly stored in the array.

So I mean **key** variable is not being evaluated when pushing array element, but **value** variable is correctly evaluated.

```
var gp = [];
var key = array[i];
var value = grades[array[i]];
gp.push({key : value});
```

Comment: post your array and grades

Comment: An object didn't work out for me because I have duplicate keys with different values.

Comment: grades is like {'a': 10, 'b: 9, 'c': 8} and array is like {a,b,c}

Comment: post the complete code along with these values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var gp = [];
var key = array[i];var value = grades[array[i]];
var obj = {};
obj[key] = value;
gp.push(obj);
```

If you use `var a = {key: value}`, the key-value-pair `a` has a key named `key`, which is just a string, just like `var a = { "key": value }`. It's not the variable `key` defined above.

Answer (score 0):

probably you need to use Object, not array.
And if you want to traverse the object values, you can use this code

```
for (var x in gp) {
  doSomethingWith(gp[x]);
}
```